# Cannot Find Google APIs for Android SDK

Tags: android, api, sdk

I've been trying to create an application that uses Google Maps and upon getting an error for "MapActivity" I searched the web and found the solution was to make my build target "Google APIs".

However, I looked in the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" in Eclipse, I could find it anywhere :(

I looked under "Third part Add-ons">"Google Inc" but it simply says "No packages found".

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of the SDK (ADK 14), the Google API packages should be located in the folder containing the appropriate SDK level in the SDK manager.

For example, for Android 2.2, there should be a folder called "Android 2.2 (API 8)" which should contain the SDK "SDK Platform" and additional pieces such as the Google APIs "Google APIs by Google, Inc.".

Answer (score 40):

I encountered the same problem

Go [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml) to manually download the Google APIs. 
For example, I use GoogleAPI level 8, so I download the package [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-8_r02.zip)

After downloading just extract the zip file to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons"` and rename the directory to `"google_apis-8"` instead of `"google_apis-8_r02"`.

Comment: Using API level 7 I've renamed my folder to addon-google_apis-google_inc_-7. Since I am on Linux, I've placed this folder in /opt/android-sdk-linux/add-ons.

Comment: @Alan Sha the page you have given(first link) is showing whole xml content.i need api 10 :(

Comment: @AndroidKiller You can find api 10 at that XML page too.
For your convenience, I've found it for you. [google_apis-10_r02.zip](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-10_r02.zip)

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me.

The simple fix was to update currently installed packages, which in turn updated the SDK Manager app, then after restarting, every appeared including the USB drivers.

Apparently, if the SD Manager is outdated, then you won't be able to install important thing like the USB driver.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem and it said "access is denied".
I am using 64bit win7 and the sdk tools is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk.
I figure out that it is because the SDK manager does not have permission to the folder so the quick fix is to right click SDK manager and run it as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I found that working with the Motorola Development studio made things very easy to pick up various API levels from Google. You can find all of the download and documentation at

[developer.motorola.com](http://developer.motorola.com)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Google Server is down or return 502 error, so you cannot find any manifest file. This happened to me. The solution is to wait for a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling SDK manager and ADT solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator did the trick from me in Windows7. SDK mgr is showing all extra google apis too after this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Restarting the Eclipse & SDK manager solved the problem. After Restart, all the GOOGLE API and other stuff are visible under the respective Build.

If this dont show any change, Invoke the SDK Manager.exe as ADMINISTRATOR and this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache (Tools > Options > Clear Cache), then 
reloading (Packages > Reload), and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an old package it is possible that it is obsolete and the SDK manager wont show it by default.  Go to "Packages" Tab and select "Show Obsolete Packages".