# How to install Google Map API for android API level 8

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm new to android n i want to develop application in Android (for 2.2 Version) with use of Google Map API i found various tutorial like this

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

[image]

but i'm unable to find how to install Google Map API for API level 8 like in this link.

Can any one please provide me the link which explains the installation of old API's because i have google Map API for level 14 but i want to install for level 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Open up your SDK Manager

[image]

Step #2: Scroll down in the list to find the API level you wish

Step #3: Check the "Google APIs" checkbox for the API level you wish

Step #4: Click the "Install packages..." button and follow the prompts

Comment: plz see sir my SDK Manager not showing any Google APIs in Android 2.2 (API 8) i'm updated my question with SDK Manager Image please check now...

Comment: @user755278: Choose Packages|Reload from the SDK Manager main menu, and see if that gives you your missing packages. Otherwise, I have no solution for you, other than to uninstall and reinstall the Android SDK.

Comment: can you provide me a little confirmation from your side you post me the Image which showing Google Api's for API leve 15 . is your SDK Maanager showing the Google Api in API level 8 if your installed or not installed because i have a doubt about this thanks...

Comment: @user755278: "is your SDK Maanager showing the Google Api in API level 8" -- of course. It is for tens of thousands of other developers worldwide.

Comment: as like i have already written a code for API level 8 and i have to integrate the map in that.

Comment: Maybe you need to restart your Eclipse

Comment: In the SDK manager: Click "Packages" on the menu bar -> check "Show Obsolete Packages".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, apparently its because the sdk manager is not updated. I didnt feel like updating so I cant confirm that part. BUT, I can confirm one way around.

Alan Sha posted a manual way to download the APIs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860557/962685

Just do what he says and it works. You will have to change your api level in your manifest and  in project settings.