# App crashing on android 4.3 on checkdevice(this) GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app works fine on versions of android below 4.3
However on 4.3 I get the the following error when I do

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(SplashActivity.this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(SplashActivity.this);
```

here is the (part of ) stracktrace :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
```

What shall I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [device does not have package com.google.android.gsf in google nexus phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901007/device-does-not-have-package-com-google-android-gsf-in-google-nexus-phone)

Comment: @adneal it is duplicated, has it been resolved tho? I found this one with answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339445/com-google-android-gsf-package-couldnt-be-found