# Unable to load map on android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I my android app I have google map apiv2 and able to display map on physical device but when try on emulator then is shows message -

> This app won't run unless you update Goolge play service.

I have updated google play service upto api level 19 and set  android:targetSdkVersion="19"  in manifest file.
[image]

and created an avd with Google Apis target and api level 19.Bus still receive same message while opening map activity.

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, referencing the Google Android Map API v2 you can't run Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator; you must use a device for your tests.

I recommend using the emulator by Genymotion instead of Google's emulators. It launches way faster and responds almost in real-time. It also supports Google Play Services and therefore Google Maps.

[download Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)

Comment: Thanks for answer @jignesh jain I was installed and test it on genymotion emulator as well but getting error while registering GCMRegistrar on Pushnotification service. The error message is - Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf  Any help on it.

Comment: create a google account and open Play Store so it can update because GCM need Google Play Services.

Comment: I just try to login on Gmail app it says this app wont run without google play service.And when try adding account via setting I select personal and then gmail it return back.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339445/com-google-android-gsf-package-couldnt-be-found

Comment: download from link and just drag drop into your emulator https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559

Comment: If you're having trouble getting google play services set up on a genymotion emulator, I've followed this method multiple times.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su